# Add AspNetCoreApp to referencing Framework

Tags: asp.net-core, reference, frameworks

I have a .NetCore Project, and want to use Kestrel webserver. To do so, I need to add the aspNetCore framework. How can I do this, ans in which file?
Thanks, Thomas.

I looked at the *.csproj file, but there is nor target framework in it.
[image]

Comment: If you want Install .NET( 7.0 or 6.0) ,You Can Download File This is Site https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download

Comment: Could you please share which framework, you would like to include? You could check [`Kestrel configuration and resource here in official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: Hi, I need to add the ASP Framework. Therefor I need a hint, how to to this. In the project-settings I don't find how to add an additional framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add to <projectname>.csproj
....
  <ItemGroup>
      <!-- Add ASP CORE -->
      <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

That's it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).